# Delete Object with View as JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got the folowing problem.
I write Regression-Tests against a databse. At the end i would clean up the created entities.
Everything works except the deletion of one entity.

The error is:

```
View or function 'OrganizationUserView' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables.
```

The JPA-Annotation is the following:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "OrganizationUserView", joinColumns = {
@JoinColumn(name = "OrganizationID")},
inverseJoinColumns = {
  @JoinColumn(name = "MemberID")}
  )
private Set<Member> members = new HashSet<>();
```

The Organization and the Member-Objects are already deleted before.

Has anyone an idea how can i delete the Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, i've used a Database-Trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER IO_Trig_DEL 
  ON  [dbo].[OrganizationUserView]
  INSTEAD OF DELETE
AS BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
END
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate entity representing the join table, mapped to the view, instead of using @JoinTable.

Discussed here (forum is dead so using archive.org): https://web.archive.org/web/20170113182538/https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=985505&sid=dc550e634938fa271b76ecf60119d189